# text side in the chapter title

Tags: lyx, tikz-styles

I used `Ti*k*Z` code in `lyx` preample to add decoration around the chapter, but the title words was not good.
example: 
the chapter before tikz: 
الحركة الدورانية
the chapter aftr i used tikz:
الدورانية الحركة

The code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
%\normalfont\scheherazade
\Huge
%\bfseries\scshape
}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=blue!30 ] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=blue!50]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel};
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=0.82\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=blue!50]
              {\color{white}#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}
```

Comment: You have an example, but it does not appear to be a complete example. Can you please provide an example that can be compiled?

Comment: this the file:http://4uploading.com/2ji8y9geq09y

Comment: Please edit your question and add there a *complete* minimal document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got 1/2 solved by adding:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
```

Add:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\tikzset{font=selectlanguage{arabic}}
```

This code worked in koma-script class.

And I used:

```
\hspace{-0.4375cm}
```

Before:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
```

Best regards